# Validate special character while entering text in Django model field

Tags: javascript, django, django-models, django-forms

I have a django model

```
class Order(AbstractOrder):
    number = models.CharField(
        _("Order Number"), max_length=40, db_index=True,
        unique=True, validators = [
            RegexValidator(
                regex=r'^[-,_\w]*$',
                message=_("Only AlphaNumerics and , - _ are allowed")
            )
        ]
    )
```

I have added the regex check for number field and on click of save it is properly validating, but my requirement is i want to validate it while entering itself, How i can achieve it, how can i integrate js to validate it.

Comment: This is not a question about Django. If you want to write some JS, just go ahead.

Comment: This is a javascript question. If you want the browser to validate input, you can't re-use your python code but need to duplicate the validation in Javascript. Just a note: If you do this, it's still important not to remove your validation on the model, because it's still possible for your users to bypass the JS validation.

Comment: If you want to validate before submitting to server you should remove this validation from model first and write js for your input type there are ways you can do it using JS. you can do that by defining regex in js and validate input or as you said if there are only few special characters you can check them at keydown event and prevent input.